# Grouping values of a vector

Tags: vector, grouping

Lets say - I have the two vectors:

```
a    numbers=[14 14 2 25 25 14 14 14 2 23 23 23]:
b    frequency_of_the_numbers_above=[2 1 2 3 1 3];

c    new_numbers=[14 14 14 14 14 2 2 2 2 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 14 14 14 14 14 2 2 2 2 23 23 23 23 ];
```

b describes how often a value in vector a appears.For example:number 14 two times, that's why first number in b is 2 ,number 2 in vector a one time that's why second number in vector b is 1 etc.

what I now want is to adapt the vector b to vector c so that the result should look like:

```
new_numbers[14 14 14 14 14 2 2 2 2 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 14 14 14 14 14 2 2 2 2 23 23 23 23 ];
frequency_numbers_for_new_numbers=[2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3];
```

Comment: your question doesn't seem to fit what's in the vectors you posted. What b seems to be is how many of a given number appears in a in a ROW. As there are 5 `14s` in a. And your result seems to be whatever number was in b repeated for the number of that element in c is that what you want? Does a and c always contain the same numbers in the same order?

Comment: Can you give your vectors more descriptive names? Naming your objects well will make the question clearer to us, and will also make any solution easier to follow.

Comment: No i have a pattern in a and b where the first number of b describes the number of same values which a neighboring in a . that means two 14s,one 2,two 25s etc. Now i want to have the value of 2 which stands for 14 in a exactly the same number ot times like in c - that means for 5 14s in c five 2s in c etc - the five 14s in c etc - i hope i could explain myself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question doesn't seem to fit what's in the vectors you posted. What b seems to be is how many of a given number appears in a in a ROW. As there are 5 14s in a. And your result seems to be whatever number was in b repeated for the number of that element in c is that what you want? Does a and c always contain the same numbers in the same order?

Well I'll write the code to do what I described (in java)

```
int index = 0;
int currentVal = c[0];
int[] result = new int[c.length];

for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
    if(c[i] != currentVal) {
        index++; //if the number changed go to the next index for b
        currentVal = c[i]; //update the currentVal to the new value
    }
    result[i] = b[index]; //copy the value from b into the result vector
}
```